# Can I return different information from a for loop to a new variable every time the loop iterates?

Tags: java, string

I have a for loop that traverses a `String`, and pulls out 2 characters each time and assigns them to a variable. The code segment I wrote is below:

```
//parse strings to integers
    public int convertStringToInt(String stringOfDigits)
    {
        int number = 0;    
        int total = 0;
        String subData = "";

        for(int n = 0; n < stringOfDigits.length() ; n+=2) //For loop to pick out 2 digit sets of numbers from a string literal
        {
            subData = stringOfDigits.substring(n, n+2); //pulls a 2 digit substring and assigns it to a variable
            number = Integer.parseInt(subData); //converts the substring to an integer
        }
    }
```

I need to somehow return the first two characters to a variable (`var1` for example), the next two characters to another variable (`var2`) and so on. Then I need to return all of that so that I can bring it into my main module.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

**Edit:**

This is my entire program. The answers I was getting were pretty complex for what I think it needs to be. Maybe a simpler solution lies somewhere else. This program prints out a bar graph displaying how many users use each operating system (linux, mac, windows) that I know. The `String` contains those numbers, and I need to get those separate two digit pairs into the `drawBar()` method so that it draws the bar with that many users.

```
/**
 * The purpose of this program is to draw a bar graph using turtle graphics
 * and object oriented programming techniques based on information from a survey on
 * Operating System use.
 * 
 * @author Andrew Hauser (Shibumi) 
 * @version 1/16/12
 */
import java.awt.*; //imports the awt module
class Survey //Declares the Survey class
{
    //Draws a line (or rectangle) from the first set of coordinates to the second set of coordinates.
    public static void drawLine(Turtle myrtle, Color color, int penWidth, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        myrtle.hide();
        myrtle.penUp();
        myrtle.setPenColor(color);
        myrtle.setPenWidth(penWidth);
        myrtle.moveTo(x1, y1);
        myrtle.penDown();
        myrtle.moveTo(x2, y2);
    }//end of method

    //Draws the box that the graph is contained in
    public static void drawBox(Turtle myrtle, Color color) 
    {
        myrtle.hide();
        myrtle.penUp();
        myrtle.setPenColor(color);
        myrtle.setPenWidth(1);
        myrtle.moveTo(100, 10);
        myrtle.penDown();
        myrtle.moveTo(400, 10);
        myrtle.moveTo(400, 250);
        myrtle.moveTo(100, 250);
        myrtle.moveTo(100, 10);
        myrtle.penUp();    
    }

    //Draws the value lines on the outside of the box
    public static void drawBoxLines(Turtle myrtle, Color color)
    {
        myrtle.hide();
        myrtle.penUp();
        myrtle.setPenWidth(1);
        myrtle.moveTo(100, 250);
        for(int nums = 0; nums <=10; nums++)
        {
            myrtle.turnLeft();
            myrtle.penDown();
            myrtle.forward(10);
            myrtle.penUp();
            myrtle.backward(10);
            myrtle.turnRight();
            myrtle.forward(20);
        }
    }


    //Draws a bar for the graph
    public static void drawBar(Turtle myrtle, Color color, int value, int x1, int y1)
    {
        myrtle.hide();
        myrtle.penUp();
        myrtle.setPenColor(color);
        myrtle.setPenWidth(1);
        myrtle.moveTo(x1, y1);
        myrtle.penDown();
        myrtle.forward(value * 10);
        myrtle.turnRight();
        myrtle.forward(10);
        myrtle.turnRight();
        myrtle.forward(value * 10);
        myrtle.penUp();
        myrtle.turnLeft();
        myrtle.turnLeft();
    }

    //parse strings to integers
    public int convertStringToInt(String stringOfDigits)
    {
        int number = 0;    
        int total = 0;
        String subData = "";

        for(int n = 0; n < stringOfDigits.length() ; n+=2) //For loop to pick out 2 digit sets of numbers from a string literal
        {
            subData = stringOfDigits.substring(n, n+2); //pulls a 2 digit substring and assigns it to a variable
            number = Integer.parseInt(subData); //converts the substring to an integer
        }
    }
}

public class SurveyTester //Declares the SurveyTester class
{
    //Executes the code.
    public static void main(String[] args) //Start of main method
    {
        World worldObj = new World(); //Makes a new world
        Turtle myrtle = new Turtle(0, 0, worldObj); //Makes a new Turtle object
        Picture pictureObj = new Picture("Graph_background.png");
        worldObj.setPicture(pictureObj);
        Survey survey = new Survey(); //Makes a new Survey object

        stringData = "031016";

        survey.drawBox(myrtle, Color.BLACK);
        survey.drawBoxLines(myrtle, Color.BLACK); //Draws lines by twos
        survey.drawBar(myrtle, Color.RED, 3, 150, 250); //Bar for linux
        survey.drawBar(myrtle, Color.RED, 10, 240, 250); //Bar for Mac
        survey.drawBar(myrtle, Color.RED, 16, 330, 250); //Bar for windows
    }
}
```

Help would be super appreciated!

PS. If you want to actually *run* this to see what it looks like, you'll need the bookClasses Java library, which you can get from my dropbox here: http://db.tt/H8zmyA75

Comment: have you tried using arrays in your situation?

Comment: Why do you need your surbet to be in "031016" in the first place. Why can't you use whitespace separated string ("03 10 16"). Or three strings, or three integers. Even if you are receiving string as result of survey, then Survey class should take care of string to integer parsing and providing graph object with ready to use data

Answer (score 0):

This is why arrays were invented. Put each pair of characters into a

```
char[][] pairs;
```

Or perhaps better an

```
ArrayList<char[]> pairs;
```

if you can't predict how many in advance.

Comment: So would I put the characters into the arrays in the main method? and then call the convertStringToInt(); with the array instead of a string literal? And How would I return those multiple sets of info? (Sorry, I'm new to this.)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java . util . * ;

//parse strings to integers
    public int convertStringToInt(String stringOfDigits)
    {
        int number = 0;    
        int total = 0;
        String subData = "";
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int n = 0; n < stringOfDigits.length() ; n+=2) //For loop to pick out 2 digit sets of numbers from a string literal
        {
            subData = stringOfDigits.substring(n, n+2); //pulls a 2 digit substring and assigns it to a variable
            numbers . add ( Integer.parseInt(subData) ) ; //converts the substring to an integer
        }
    }
```

Comment: So where does that get returned then? Sorry, I'm fairly new to Java, and I haven't gotten to arrays yet.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question you want to create multiple variables based on the size of the string. And that Each **two** characters in your string represent **one** Integer.
An Array could be described as a list of variables. 
So if you have a 10 character string , those 10 characters represent 5 integers.
So you will need an array of **length** 5 (the number of variables in the array or 'cells')

To create an array of integers :

```
int[] arrayName = new int[SIZE];
```

you will also return the array and handle that as a 'list' of variables

For Example :

```
public static int [] convertStringToInteger(String toConvert) {

int [] toReturn = new int[toConvert.length()/2];
        //Assuming passed strings are of even length


for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < toConvert.length() || j < toReturn.length; i +=2 , j++) {

    String temp = toConvert.charAt(i) + "" + toConvert.charAt(i+1);

    toReturn [j] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
}


return toReturn;
}
```

Arrays are very easy to use and understand you can check Arrays in the Java tutorials by oracle [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Hope this Helps.